# Built-in Ethernet not working

Tags: macos, ethernet

I am using a 13" MacBook Pro (mid 2012) and I have upgraded to OS X 10.11 El Capitan a while ago. Last night before going to bed I switched off the computer. Since this working the built-in Ethernet that was working fine does not seem to work anymore. I have deleted the network interfaces and rebooted the system, but still it does not show up in the network preferences. Is there a fix? What should I do?

Comment: this link has the solution https://discussions.apple.com/message/29844595#29844595

Comment: Can you post this as an answer (and include the essential parts directly in it)?

Answer (score 1):

For a very short window (a few hours) - Apple pushed an update that disabled the ethernet driver for some of the Macs.

If you can connect to WiFi and run this command:

```
sudo softwareupdate --background
```

That would fix the issue if yours failed to operate due to this bug. The details are covered at

- https://support.apple.com/HT205956

Also some more details are on this post:

- [Ethernet not working on MacBook pro retina 13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229214/)